# CEFSharp ChromiumBrowser does not load content on Load(url) invocation?

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am using [CEFSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) to build a very simple browser in C# using WinForms. The only functionality I need is to clear all cookies instantly and to set custom user agent string.

This used to work brilliantly before the recent update to version 79 from an older version of CEFSharp. Due to deprecation of some functionality, I had to implement several new interfaces, like for example `ICookieAccessFilter` (see the full listing below).

Once done, my browser stopped showing the new content. On calling `Load(url)` method, I see the following methods from my interface implementation being called (in this order):

```
OnBeforeBrowse
GetResourceRequestHandler
GetCookieAccessFilter
OnBeforeResourceLoad
GetResourceHandler
OnResourceResponse
GetResourceResponseFilter
```

Still, nothing is shown in the browser. If I right-click on the browser window and choose "View source", I get the default source for the blank page to see:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

In the debug I see that the Address property of the browser was changed, but still, no content shown (just blank screen)

[image: Address property changes]

I believe something might be wrong with my "poor man's" interface implementations, but I already checked them several time against the [sample applications](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/master/CefSharp.WinForms.Example) on CEFSharp GitHub repository and I don't see anything wrong.

Here is the full source of that interface.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.Callback;

namespace CustomWebBrowser
{
    public class CustomRequestHandler : IRequestHandler
    {
        public string UserAgent { get; set; }

        public string CookiePath { get; set; }

        public bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool userGesture, bool isRedirect)
        {
            return false;
        }

        bool IRequestHandler.OnOpenUrlFromTab(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture)
        {
            return this.OnOpenUrlFromTab(browserControl, browser, frame, targetUrl, targetDisposition, userGesture);
        }

        public IResourceRequestHandler GetResourceRequestHandler(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame,
            IRequest request, bool isNavigation, bool isDownload, string requestInitiator, ref bool disableDefaultHandling)
        {
            return new CustomResourceRequestHandler(this);
        }

        public bool GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, bool isProxy, string host,
            int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
        {
            callback.Dispose();
            return false;
        }

        bool IRequestHandler.OnCertificateError(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, CefErrorCode errorCode, string requestUrl, ISslInfo sslInfo, IRequestCallback callback)
        {
            return false;
        }

        void IRequestHandler.OnPluginCrashed(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string pluginPath)
        {
        }

        void IRequestHandler.OnRenderProcessTerminated(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, CefTerminationStatus status)
        {
        }

        bool IRequestHandler.OnQuotaRequest(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, long newSize, IRequestCallback callback)
        {
            return false;
        }

        void IRequestHandler.OnRenderViewReady(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
        {
        }


        protected virtual bool OnOpenUrlFromTab(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public bool OnSelectClientCertificate(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, bool isProxy, string host, int port, X509Certificate2Collection certificates, ISelectClientCertificateCallback callback)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void OnResourceRedirect(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response, ref string newUrl)
        {

        }

        public bool CanGetCookies(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool CanSetCookie(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, Cookie cookie)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class CustomResourceRequestHandler : IResourceRequestHandler
    {
        public CustomRequestHandler Handler { get; }
        public ICookieAccessFilter GetCookieAccessFilter(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame,
            IRequest request)
        {
            return new CustomCookieAccessFilter();
        }

        public CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request,
            IRequestCallback callback)
        {
            var headers = request.Headers;

            var userAgent = headers["User-Agent"];
            headers["User-Agent"] = Handler.UserAgent;
            request.Headers = headers;

            return CefReturnValue.Continue;
        }

        public IResourceHandler GetResourceHandler(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request)
        {
            return new CustomResourceHandler();
        }

        public void OnResourceRedirect(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request,
            IResponse response, ref string newUrl)
        {

        }

        public bool OnResourceResponse(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request,
            IResponse response)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public IResponseFilter GetResourceResponseFilter(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame,
            IRequest request, IResponse response)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void OnResourceLoadComplete(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request,
            IResponse response, UrlRequestStatus status, long receivedContentLength)
        {

        }

        public bool OnProtocolExecution(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public CustomResourceRequestHandler(CustomRequestHandler handler)
        {
            Handler = handler;
        }
    }

    public class CustomResourceHandler : ResourceHandler
    {

        public bool ProcessRequest(IRequest request, ICallback callback)
        {
            return true;
        }


    }

    public class CustomCookieAccessFilter : ICookieAccessFilter
    {
        public bool CanSendCookie(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, Cookie cookie)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool CanSaveCookie(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response,
            Cookie cookie)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For simplicity extend the new RequestHandler and ResourceRequestHandler implementations see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-interception for an example. Only override the methods you require. Your GetResourceHandler method should return null if you wish for the default behaviour,  your custom class will load every request with an empty response.